# Django Model Data dynamic with column name and value

Tags: django

During django create new records in dynamic way got error, ID is expection number but got 'OrderNo= "Order No", OrderSuffix= "Order Suffix", Reference= "Reference", ItemCode= "Item Code", QtyOrdered= "Qty Ordered", QtyShipped= "Qty Shipped", Warehouse= "Warehouse", DispatchDate= "Dispatch Date", TrackingNo= "Tracking No", CarrierCode= "Carrier Code"'

But if i put this string like below its working fine

```
data = shipment(OrderNo= "Order No", OrderSuffix= "Order Suffix", Reference= "Reference", ItemCode= "Item Code", QtyOrdered= "Qty Ordered", QtyShipped= "Qty Shipped", Warehouse= "Warehouse", DispatchDate= "Dispatch Date", TrackingNo= "Tracking No", CarrierCode= "Carrier Code") #shipment is the model
```

```
for row in table:
            ind = 0
            rowdata = ''
            for col in config['header_columns']:
                rowdata += col['title'] + '= "' + row[ind] + '"' + ', '
                ind = ind + 1
            rowdata = rowdata[:-2]
            #return HttpResponse(rowdata)
            data = shipment(rowdata) #shipment is the model
            data.save(using="integration")
```

[image]

That means created string variable if i put directly for make it dynamic its showing "ID" expected a number but the string if i put its totally working fine.

May anyone help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cannot construct one string that *looks like* Python source code and expect it to work like Python source code. `shipment(rowdata)` passes exactly one argument to `shipment`, regardless of what the contents of that argument look like. Please provide a sample of your data so we can show you the correct way. In some way or another, you'll want to produce a *dict* which you pass with *argument unpacking*: `shipment(**rowdata)`.

Comment: Completely understand your saying.Actually i have yaml file to get the header which is the table column so i want to make this table column name (config['header_columns']) and data row from table is need to put against the column name.
So sometimes column may reduce/increate so the row data also need to change.
That means sometime 10 column and 10 data but if we found 9 column so we are picking only 9 data.Thats why i made the string and pass into model.

Please help me to put this column and values record increase and decrease accordingly dont effect to save the data.

Comment: `rowdata = dict((col['title'], i) for col, i in zip(config['header_columns'], table))` `shipment(**rowdata)` — Something along these lines…?

Comment: Exactly this way.Let me try and let you know


```for row in table:
            ind = 0
            for col in config['header_columns']:
                rowdata += col['title'] + '= "' + row[ind] + '"' + ', '
                ind = ind + 1
            rowdata = dict((col['title'], i) for col, i in zip(config['header_columns'], table)) data = shipment(**rowdata)
            data.save(using="integration")
```
Like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producing a string that looks like Python code doesn't work. You want to produce a `dict` which you then unpack into separate arguments, e.g.:

```
for row in table:
    rowdata = dict((col['title'], i) for col, i in zip(config['header_columns'], row))
    data = shipment(**rowdata)
```